# leiningen's run task in clojure with cake

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have recently started looking at cake as an alternative to leiningen as it uses a single jvm instance and so is much faster. However, its `run` task is not quite the same as leiningen's and I can't find any task in cake that just runs the `-main` method in the namespace I specify in the `project.clj` file. Does cake have any such task?

On the other hand, I tried writing a custom *cake task* which launched the app for me, but I was getting import errors, which make me think that may be the complete `CLASSPATH` is not built when the tasks are executed.

So, is there a task with *cake* that is equivalent to `lein run`?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't currently exist. I'll add it.

The current run task just runs a file. Try passing it a Clojure file to run.

Comment: Thank you Rayne. Looking forward to this :)

Answer (score 0):

cake is advancing quickly and so far as I understand it run is supposed to be the same. 
Make sure you are running the latest cake code (because it changes often) and perhaps 
you will get it fixed if you bring it up on the mailing list.

Comment: I just downloaded cake and checked, I must be doing something wrong. When I run `lein run`, the app loads, but when I do `cake run`, I get the error http://paste.pocoo.org/show/378248/ I don't get why its trying to load the directory.

Comment: That looks like broken cake :(

Comment: should I put this up on the cake's mailing list? What do you think?

Comment: 'cake' isn't really trying to just copy Leiningen and thus there are likely lots of cases where something that works x way in leinginen works y way in cake. It doesn't necessarily imply youth as much as it implies that we just decided to do something differently.

Comment: Rayne, I understand cake's goals might vary from those of leiningen. I just wanted to know how a simple `run` of an application is done with cake. I'm kind of identifying that task with lein's run command.